# How can I clean my laptop keyboard?

Tags: cleaning, keys, laptop

I need to clean my keyboard for my Lenovo laptop. The space of the strokes are very low.

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/237/

Comment: thanks, John but I am going to clean laptop keyboard not a desktop keyboard and the difference is space in keys and between them so you can't do it like that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a canister of compressed air. Shoot quick blasts of air directly at the "crud" between the keys. Don't spray continuously for more than 1-2 seconds, or the air will get too cold and may damage your laptop.

I also recommend doing this outside, so the crud that flies out of your keyboard doesn't make a mess on the floor.

Comment: so where can I found a compressed air?

Comment: Electronics stores usually sell canisters of it. In the United States, places like Best Buy will sell it. You can also find it online, on Amazon.com.

Answer (score 1):

First, to clean a laptop keyboard, you must disassemble it to reach the membrane of the keys, now if you just want to clean the surface of the keyboard, you must pass a towel or paper slightly soft and moist to remove a little dust or even spots on the letters. This action must be carefully applied since a drop of liquid that penetrates the inside of the keyboard could affect the long-term functionalities of the keyboard.

Comment: thanks, but I can't disassemble my keyboard is somehow impossible or the warranty is going to go because I opened this.

Comment: Use a towel slightly moistened with water to clean the surface of the keys.

Comment: and something else, it's not just dust, its eaten chips, some soda and even rice and...

Comment: With the moistened towel you can clean part of some residue that has fallen from liquid, now for a higher proportion object (like rice grains), you could use a blower. Or in last option a thin pin, of which you use to sew, you pass it lightly by the place where the rice grains are stuck until they are out.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've pried up all the keys one at a time and really cleaned up the crud which accumulated beneath them.   All are easily removed and replaced.  The long keys which have guide wires beneath them require special care in replacing, but they all seemed to go back and function again.  Surprising all that junk has been sitting under the keys.  LOL

Answer (score 1):

A useful hack that I have seen passed around is to use Post-It notes and scoop up dirt with their glue-covered edge when moving that below a row of keys.

Later I modified that technique and now use strong tape (duct tape style, the stronger the better). I take a small spatula (ideally one with a bent head) and wrap it with the tape outside-in, then move that below the row of keys.

(Now that I say it, using double-sided tape to cover the spatula could be even simpler as the tape can not get "lost" below the keys as it would stick to the spatula head.)

Answer (score 1):

One more eeasy method that you can use a soft brush to clean your laptop keyboard ,it's also not harmful for your laptop,and don't waste your time or energy.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a toothbrush** to remove dirt in between the narrow spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are gels and gums which you can use to clean keyboards. Previously, I have used a guar based gum to clean keyboards and fans. I hate prying keyboard keys unless absolutely necessary.