# How to effectively clean Laptop keyboard safely

Tags: cleaning, laptop

How to I clean laptop's keyboard without ruining it 
A lot of dust gets stuck in between keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clean my laptop keyboard?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20188/how-can-i-clean-my-laptop-keyboard)

Comment: @Chenmunka How can this be duplicate, this question can arise in any person's mind does anyone have copyright of this question so that only they have the right to think of this particular question? And how would I know if it's already been asked

Comment: @user74981 Chenmunka is right, the principle is that you are supposed to check that the question hasn't already been asked been asked before you ask it. The general idea being that you should have made some attempt to find the answer yourself before asking it.

Comment: @Lefty Thanks I got it :) How can I check btw?

Comment: @user74981 Personally, I just check by using the "Search on Lifehacks" box at the top of the page using keywords much as you would in Google. But I suspect that other people have better ways, because I'm often rebuked on SE sites for duplicate questions that I wasn't able to find when I searched. Maybe someone else will enlighten us both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disconnect keyboard from PC/Mac (if not a laptop): you don’t want to be pressing random keys. If a laptop, turn off.
2. Tip it upside down and give it a few shakes and a few good whacks.
3. Tip it back over and if needed, use a shaving brush or soft makeup brush (lots of soft bristles) and get as far under the keys as you can.
4. Can of compressed air if needed.
5. Wipe down with anything safe to use on plastic. I use window cleaner and a soft cloth (old T-shirt or a microfibre tea towel). Mr Sheen also works as does Armourall. Even warm water with a little dishwashing liquid is fine, just don't make the cloth more than damp.
6. If anything else like a stubborn breadcrumb is still lodged, gently lever key up a few mm and blow compressed air.
7. Reconnect PC/Mac.

Answer (score 1):

In fear of stating the obvious, the *safest* way is to use a vacuum cleaner to remove as much of the dust as possible. Then use an air duster to loosen any stubborn dust and vacuum AGAIN to remove the freshly-loosened material. This will get you the best result for the least effort. Anything beyond that will involve popping the keys out of the keyboard and using some kind of cleaning fluid and a cloth to remove dust/dirt.

Comment: I did that years ago on an Acer laptop and ended up with a few keys missing. With some laptops the keys kan be pulled of easily I guess. So I would advise against a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: @Tim You certainly need to put your vacuum on it's lowest setting before using it on your keyboard. Even then, you need to be clever with the way you use it - angling the nozzle to draw less air from around the keyboard. If all else fails, the keys are unlikely to have been damaged by the experience, so you can always open up the vacuum, remove the keys, give them a clean and re-attach them.

Answer (score 0):

Air duster would be the best bet to clean any electronic part as well hard to reach spaces without touching it, sometime body static can failed critical parts of the circuit.

[Air Duster](https://www.google.com/search?q=air%20duster&safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEJ_enUS831US831&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpxu3the7hAhUFn-AKHUHrCJAQ_AUIDigB&biw=1520&bih=699)